# Python: pandas dataframe condition for slice of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change the content in a slice of the pandas dataframe column that has 'ABC' ONLY in the column if the condition is fulfill.
I try the code as below but it return this error

> ```
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
> ```

```
 print df

   Item  Price  Quantity
0  ABC    10     30
1  ABB    20     50 
2  ABC    37     89
3  ABG    5      78

con1 = df['Price']>10
con2 = df['Quantity']>20
df[df['Item']=='ABC'].loc[con1 & con2,'Item'] = 'ABCD'

Output that I want

   Item  Price  Quantity
0  ABC    10     30
1  ABB    20     50 
2  ABCD   37     89
3  ABG    5      78
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning is caused by the chained indexing (first making a slice and then using `.loc`  on that slice). `df['Item']=='ABC'` is just another condition that you can use in `.loc`:

```
df.loc[con1 & con2 & (df['Item']=='ABC'), 'Item'] = 'ABCD'
```

Answer (score 1):

`con1 = df['Price']>10
 con2 = df['Quantity']>20
 con3 = df['Item'] == 'ABC'
 df['Item'][(con1) & (con2) & (con3)] = 'ABCD'`

Comment: This approach will generate a SettingWithCopyWarning warning.